# Firemonkey application is not response when input has focus

Tags: android, delphi

I build Delphi 10.1 update 1 example ScrollableFormDemo on Android.

- Sony Z1 D6503 virtual keyboard work well
- But on Lenovo TAB 2 A7-30HC, when I focus textbox application is not response, It show "Wait or Close dialog"

I create new app has only one TEdit or TMemo. On Lenovo , my app is not response too.

Comment: Sony Z1 D6503: Android 5.1; Lenovo TAB 2 A7-30HC: Android 4.4.2 or 5.0;

Comment: Sony Z1 D6503: Android 6.0.1; Lenovo TAB 2 A7-30HC: Android 5.0.1;